In Asgardeo, Is there a way to show a customized consent form during signup, about how their data being used?
I'm trying to configure a web application with Asgardeo authentication. I would prefer a signup flow where I can get the user's "I agree" to monitor his/her interactions with the website. (Eg : the frequently browsed pages, searched content inside the application). is there a way to make this possible?
I went through the documentation but couldn't find such option.

From my understanding of Asgardeo, this is currently not possible OOTB but it should have been considered as a roadmap item. And also this should be possible through custom layout option which is an enterprise tier branding capability which could be more cleaner.
But as a work around, it should be possible to add a new attribute and gather the consent information on the signup page.

Login to console

Navigate to attribute page

Proceed with new attribute creation (eg: display name => I agree to share my information

Mark this attribute Display this attribute on the user's profile and Make this attribute required on the user's profile

Run your application and try signup and this attribute will be preserved.



